# How could a Linnaean Siren cover its private parts?

Tags: clothing, merfolk

The sirens are roughly human, but they have 2 fins in place of arms that connect to the sides of the chest, but not to the abdomen. The sirens also do not have pelves or legs, with the body ending at the abdomen, which is a rounded cone-shape. They live in the water, but can obtain metals and fabric, and are as dextrous and intelligent as humans.

Could these sirens cover their chest and the end of their abdomen?

Comment: How can they be "as dexterous" as humans with only fins (e.g. without opposable thumbs)?

Comment: @Jedediah humans are dexterous because of wrist flexibility not because of tumbs...we could do everything we do without tumbs...two fingers would be enough...even a pair of crab pinchers would do fine

Comment: @Vesrie I'm fairly certain that isn't true.  When I was younger, I often challenged myself to complete simple tasks without using my thumbs - and even with practice it is simply not as efficient to manipulate objects without the high-strength pinch your opposed thumb gives you.  Try tying your shoes without thumbs, then get back to me.

Comment: @Jedediah not even joking. I just tried and tied* my shoes using the index, middle and anular fingers only...took half a minute probs....as a literal first time...imagine if I had a few years of practice.

Comment: @Vesrie "Lached"?  Are we talking about the same thing?

Comment: @Jedediah my bad. Mixed up words

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Anything that slips on from the bottom up would work

[image]

Your sirens do not have and hip/leg structures to hold things on, but they would still have practical shoulders.  So you just need a one piece outfit that can be pulled up and over the shoulders that is closed off at the bottom and it should hold on and keep you covered just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Tubino:

[image]

Chiton

[image]

Robe

[image]

Mantles

[image]

Apron

[image]

You have a lot of options, armless humans still manage to wear lots of clothes...and you could do some designs yourself, its quite easy.

Comment: Forgive me if I messed up some clothes names, sorrymansen I'm not a fashionista.

Comment: The apron, robe, and chiton seem to need a pelvis/lumbar-lordosis in order to stay on, and the tubino and mantle wouldn't work with the fins

Comment: A chiton is a simple cylinder, suspended on the shoulders. The girdle is purely for aesthetics. (It makes for beautiful folds.)

Comment: The chiton also seems to be too close around the arms, so it might not work for the siren

Comment: @IchthysKing: In its unfolded form a chiton is a roughly square piece of cloth with the side a little longer than the height of the wearer. First, if you are a woman, you fold a strip on top, about the height of your head; you get a rectangle with the top doubled. Then you fold it in two along the vertical axis. With one hand you pick the vertical fold, and step inside. Then you clasp the front and back parts on your left and right shoulders with brooches. Finally, you use a girdle for effect and to adjust the height of the bottom hem. It is definitely **not** a tight fitting garment.

Comment: Chitons do not cover the body from below, so it would work for the aquatic sirens

Comment: *wouldn't, not would

Answer (score -1):

clothing.

I am sure I am not really alone in this, but they can just make clothing that suits their needs.

Comment: But what sort of clothing?

Comment: Clothing such as....? You know that there are thousands of different pieces of clothing made by humans in the history of our species, and not all of them seem suitable for this particular species (you won't likely see this me-person wearing a tuxedo). This simply doesn't answer the question in any useful way.